# Wordpress QP_Query operator

Tags: wordpress

I trying to create a query to get some news from category A,B,C

I wont a article which is in all categories.

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => catalog
    [order] => DESC
    [orderby] => date
    [status] => publish
    [paged] => 1
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => catalog_category
                    [field] => id
                    [include_children] => 1
                    [operator] => AND
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12
                            [1] => 17
                            [2] => 43
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

If I use "operator" "IN" I get all articles if I use "AND" I get none results.

List of my cats and articles:

[image]

As you can see, I have only 1 article in all 3 categories.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Are you 10000% sure you have an article that is in those exact three categories?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I added a picture to my question

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's happening here. Technically what you are doing seems correct, but maybe that specific query doesn't support that specific operator, no idea. You are sure the articles are all published and OK?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes, if I have no category filter, I see all of them

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems fine but not sure what is wrong, anyways, as an alternative you may give it a try to get all posts (custom post type = `catalog`) which belongs to all three categories in (`a`, `b` and `c`), not less/more but exact match of all categories.

```
$cat_Ids = array();
// get id from each category name
foreach(array('a', 'b', 'c') as $cat) {
    $cat_Ids[] = get_cat_ID($cat)
}
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'catalog', // <-- post type is 'catalog', not 'news', right ?
    'category__and' => $cat_Ids,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'status' => 'publish'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```